# Why my code just works if obj==null?

Tags: java, object, reference, null

I was reading about private and I found this code ... I do not understand why when I put `obj == 0` or `obj == 1` I get error and the code does not work, but it just works when `obj == null`.
Can you describe to me how the code works and why it just works when `obj == null`?

```
package person;

public class Cat {

    private static Cat obj = null;

    public Cat object () {
        if(obj == null){
            obj = new Cat();
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.print("obj is null");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat myobj = new Cat();
        myobj.display();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
obj is null
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to compare a cat with an integer ? The compiler doesn't know how to handle that.

Comment: "null" is a special literal. It can be cast to any reference type. where as 0 or 1 is primitive integer number not Cat Type.

Comment: please, accept the answer of @RamanSB as correct

Comment: Can I fix the code to make obj == 0; works ?

Comment: I have to wait in 6 min to accept it brother

Comment: word "private" has nothing to main thread "null" and comparison. Discussion about never executed code (`object`) ... seems "the Copy & Paste method" without understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot point a cat reference to an int primitive, it makes no sense.

It works with null, because all references can be set to null. Null just means that the reference is pointing to nothing.

Comment: Nope, you cant compare Cat with "0". Why do you want to compare a "Cat" with an integer?

Comment: So class Cat must be comoared to null ... I just want to learn myself , that is why I asked about that ..

Comment: Yes, you can compare ANY object with null in order to know if that field references to an actual instance. But for example you can not compare int,float,boolean (primitives) with null because primitives are not Objects in Java.

Comment: You can compare to a Cat type or other references, because cat is a reference type and 0 an 1 are primitive types. You cannot compare them. If you have an instance variable which is a reference it is instantiated to null by default. Research more on the term null, for further clarifications.

Comment: @java let me know if you want me to expand on anything I have mentioned.

Comment: Can you look at @Aurasphere (it is below your answer) and to my comments on it to correct the errors .. thanks

Comment: @java I have commented on his post. 

The best thing for you to do, is to research about the difference between primitives and reference type variables and the values they can take... It won't take very long and you'll learn a lot from it.

Comment: He seems to intermingle how comparement works in Java vs C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

When it's null it works because the object is created correctly in your constructor:

```
if(obj==null){
        obj=new Cat();
    }
```

You get an error when you set your obj to 1 or 0 because the JVM doesn't know how to cast an integer to your Cat class.
If you need the obj to be an integer you can declare it as an int instead of Cat.

Comment: do you mean like this : private static int obj==1;

Comment: I did also change if(obj==null){ to if(obj==1){ but the problem that in this line obj=new Cat(); I get error : "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Cat to int" ... In the same time in this line return obj; I get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Cat"... How to fix that ? thanks

Comment: Once you declare obj as a static int variable you cannot say obj = new Cat(); That would imply obj is being instantiated as a Cat object, this is not possible as you have declared it as an int in your first comment.

Comment: Did You see, this code (a kind of singleton copied from somewhere) is not executed, analyse has nothing to real results? Dont use words like "works" as unclear - "compile" or not copile, "execute" od not execute.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you cannot compare primitive types with objects. In general, Java is type safe as described in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety#Java)

C++ on the other hand supports more implicit type casting (and has different type system from Java) where checks like obj == 0 are a possible way to check for null pointer on object.

Answer (score -2):

> Can I fix the code to make `obj == 0;` works ?

No, you can't. But you can make `addressOf(obj) == 0;` work with an ugly hack:

```
package person;

import sun.misc.Unsafe;
import util.Dirty;

public class Cat {

    private static Cat obj = null;

    public Cat object () {
        if(addressOf(obj) == 0){
            obj = new Cat();
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.print("obj is null");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat myobj = new Cat();
        myobj.display();
    }

    static final Unsafe UNSAFE = /* ... */;
    static final int REF_SIZE = /* ... */;
    static final int OBJECT_ARRAY_BASE = UNSAFE.arrayBaseOffset(Object[].class);

    public static long addressOf(Object o) {
        return addressOf(o, REF_SIZE);
    }

    public static long addressOf(Object o, int oopSize) {
        Object[] array = new Object[]{o};
        switch (oopSize) {
            case 4:
                return UNSAFE.getInt(array, OBJECT_ARRAY_BASE) & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
            case 8:
                return UNSAFE.getLong(array, OBJECT_ARRAY_BASE);
            default:
                throw new Error("unsupported address size: " + oopSize);
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is for testing purpose only and [should not be used in productive code](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/dangerous-code-how-to-be-unsafe-with-java-classes-objects-in-memory/).

Comment: answer is totally at different level than question and nothing made simpler (make all complex). To tell the true, old programmer dont understand WHY You write such code. Down from me, sorry

Comment: I just appended the ``addressOf``code and showed how it might be possible to compare the *address* of an object with ``0`` (like in C). Does old programmer understand now?

Comment: Old C/C++/Java programmer understand code how MIGHT BE possible, but WHY HERE ? Thread is for the beginners, I think ...

Comment: It is possible, but considered *unsafe*, and the thread is for everyone - WHY NOT HERE?

Comment: Original cite from SO "I have read at wikipedia about servlet and saw at YT how to do JEE, why my code is not working"  Polish media has action "Złota Czcionka" = "Gold Fonf" to recapitulate the "best" public posts

Comment: hmmm ... OK... I will make undo of "down". SO engine say edition in answer is required